# Can't connect to instance via floating IPs, not natting/forwarding properly

Tags: networking, nat, forwarding, openstack

I'm having trouble getting floating IPs to work properly on my OpenStack
setup. It looks like the controller node (running nova-network) isn't
forwarding the traffic to the instances.

I've got a Folsom deployment with FlatDHCP, not running multi-host,
running on Ubuntu 12.04.

As an example, here's a running instance with a fixed IP of 10.40.0.2 and a
floating IP of 10.20.0.3:

```
$ nova list
+-------+---------+--------+------------------------------+
| ID    | Name    | Status | Networks                     |
+-------+---------+--------+------------------------------+
| 3d292 | quantal | ACTIVE | private=10.40.0.2, 10.20.0.3 |
+-------+---------+--------+------------------------------+
```

If I'm logged into the controller, I can ping and ssh to the VM instance from
either of the IPs. However, I cannot ping or ssh to the instance from
an external machine.

If I try to ping from a machine on a different network (192.168.3.5), I can
see the packets reach the controller on its public interface (eth3), but those
packets aren't getting forwarded to the bridge (br100) that's connected to the private interface:

```
# tcpdump -i any icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
20:33:12.908188 IP 192.168.3.5 > 10.20.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 58378, seq 0, length 64
20:33:13.910759 IP 192.168.3.5 > 10.20.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 58378, seq 1, length 64
20:33:14.910591 IP 192.168.3.5 > 10.20.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 58378, seq 2, length 64
```

I've configured nova-network to use the "no-op" firewall driver, so there
shouldn't be any security group issues here:

```
firewall_driver=nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver
```

I've confirmed that I have IP forwarding enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

I'm not too familiar with iptables, but looking at the rules (see https://gist.github.com/lorin/5209761),
I can't see anything obviously wrong.

I assume this rule is in effect when connecting from the controller to the VM:

```
-A nova-network-OUTPUT -d 10.20.0.3/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.40.0.2
```

And that it hits these rules when doing forward

```
-A nova-network-PREROUTING -d 10.20.0.3/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.40.0.2
-A nova-network-FORWARD -o br100 -j ACCEPT
```

At this point, I'm at a loss as to why it isn't doing the NAT properly and
forwarding the packets.

The interfaces are:

- `eth0`: (not involved here)
- `eth1`: connects to the internal VM-only network, br100 is bridged to it. Packets should ultimately go out that interface
- `eth2`: (not involved here)
- `eth3`: public-facing interface. It has the IP of the controller (10.20.0.2), as
  well as the floating IP of the instance (10.20.0.3).

Below is the output of "ip a", with MACs obscured.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet 169.254.169.254/32 scope link lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.30.0.131/24 brd 10.30.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 ef23::2345:3aff:fe86:50c8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br100 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 11:22:33:44:55:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 ef23::2345:3aff:fe86:50c9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 77:88:99:00:11:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.0.131/24 brd 10.10.0.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 ef23::2345:3aff:fe68:b4b6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 33:44:55:66:77:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.0.2/24 brd 10.20.0.255 scope global eth3
    inet 10.20.0.3/32 scope global eth3
    inet6 ef23::2345:3aff:fe68:b4b7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 54:78:1a:86:50:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.40.0.1/16 brd 10.40.255.255 scope global br100
    inet6 ef23::2345:3aff:fed1:cd55/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Routing table:

```
~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth2
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.20.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
10.30.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.40.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br100
```

Bridge setup:

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br100       8000.54781a8650c9   no      eth1
```

Here are some networking lines from /etc/nova/nova.conf

```
network_manager=nova.network.manager.FlatDHCPManager
flat_interface=eth1
flat_network_bridge=br100
public_interface=eth3
firewall_driver=nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say under "The interfaces are" that eth2 isn't involved
but from the route output it looks like the gateway is set up for eth2.

I think you would want it set up on eth3.  I'd check that /etc/network/interfaces is set up to reflect that.